# Loop in lua is supposed to modify values of an array but it does not

Tags: arrays, lua

Here's the loop:

```
array={0x, 0y, 1x, 1y}
for i, v in ipairs(array) do
    if (i%2)==0 then
        array[i]=v+valuex
    else
        array[i]=v+valuey
    end
end
```

What i think it should do is cycle through the array and add either the variable 'valuex' if the position of the array variable is pair and 'valuey' if it's not: array[i] is the position, and I add 'valuex/y' to its 'v' value, but in the end nothing end up happening.

In the other hand, this code works, and it's what i'm trying to make the loop achieve:

```
0x=0x+valuex
1x=1x+valuex
0y=0y+valuey
1y=1y+valuey
```

I really can't get my hand on the reason the loop doesn't do that, but in the same time, you've guessed it, i'm a beginner in lua and in programming in general so i'd appreciate if you could lend me a hand.
Thanks.

Comment: `0x`, etc, is a syntax error. Do you mean `x0`, etc?

Comment: 0x, etc are variables which i cut off part of their name for a better lisibility, they originally start with letters and not numbers. I can provide full original code if the loop above on its own seems fine

Comment: Maybe not the whole code, but do post enough for us to be able to run it. [Details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, as you state in a comment, that `0x` et. al. are in fact variables, your code was *never* going to work.

Variables *are not values*; they're variables. Variables *store* values, but they are not themselves values.

When you created your array, you copied the values inside of those variables into the array. Those array entries are modified, but there is no association between the array entries and where they got their values from.

If you want to manipulate the variables themselves, then they would have to be part of some table (perhaps the global table), the array indices would have to be the string names of those values, and your modifying function would have to use `v` to access the variable from the table. Assuming your "`0x`" variables are entries in the global table, the code would look something like this:

```
array={"0x", "0y", "1x", "1y"} --Storing string names of the variables.
for i, v in ipairs(array) do
    if (i % 2) == 0 then
        _G[v] = _G[v] + valuex
    else
        _G[v] = _G[v] + valuey
    end
end
```